# How can I post data in database by showing data from another table in Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem with my View. I have a Product Model and I want to add products. In it, there is a **dropdownlist** of category Name which is coming from another model. I want to select the category and then get the ID of that Category and put it in my Product Model Because it had a foreign key of that category. Basically, I want the category name to be shown as well as if someone selects it .it should post the Id of that Category so that I can put it in my product model.

**This is My Product View**

```
@using Test2.Models;
@model ViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Product";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/masternav1.cshtml";


}

<h2>Product</h2>

<link href="~/Scripts/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@using (@Html.BeginForm("Product", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="container">
        <form action="action_page.php">

            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/product.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar" />

            </div>

       @Html.Partial("_AdminProduct",Model.Productmodel)


            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Productmodel.pro_fk_cat, new SelectList(new string[] { "Select Category", Model.CategoryModel.CategoryName }, "Select Category"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })


              <div>  

                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-success btn-block" />
                <span style="color:red;">@ViewBag.error </span>

            </div>

            <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
                <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
}
```

**This is my Product Partial VIew.**

```
@model Test2.Models.Product

<div>
    <label for="uname"><b>Product Name</b></label>
    @*<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required="required">**@
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ProductName, new { @placeholder = "Product Name", @required = "required" })
    <br />
    <label for="psw"><b>Upload Image</b></label>
    @*<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>*@
    <input type="file" name="Imgfile" id="Imgfile" class="form-control" required="required" />
    <br />
    <label for="psw"><b>Product Discription</b></label>
    @*<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>*@
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.ProductDes, new { @placeholder = "Product Discription", @required = "required", @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    <label for="psw"><b>Product Price</b></label>
    @*<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>*@
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Productprice, new { @placeholder = "Product Price", @required = "required" })
    <br />

    <label for="psw"><b>Product Category</b></label>
    @*@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.pro_fk_cat, new SelectList(Model.),"Select Category")*@


</div>
```

**This is my Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Product()
        {
            if (Session["ad_id"] == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AdminLogin");
            }
           ViewModel mymodel = new ViewModel();
            mymodel.CategoryData = GetCategory();
            mymodel.Productmodel = GetProduct();
            return View(mymodel);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Product(Product p,HttpPostedFileBase Imgfile)
        {
            string path = uploadingfile(Imgfile);
            if (path.Equals("-1"))
            {
                ViewBag.error = "Image Could not be Uploaded";
            }
            else
            {
                Product pro = new Product();


                pro.ProductName = p.ProductName;
                pro.ProductImage = path;
                pro.ProductDes = p.ProductDes;
                pro.Productprice = p.Productprice;
                pro.pro_fk_ad = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ad_id"].ToString());
                pro.pro_fk_cat = p.pro_fk_cat;
                db.Products.Add(pro);

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Category");
            }

            return View();
        }
```

**This is my product model**

```
namespace Test2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductImage { get; set; }
        public string ProductDes { get; set; }
        public int Productprice { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> pro_fk_cat { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> pro_fk_ad { get; set; }

        public virtual Admintb Admintb { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**This is my Category Model**

```
namespace Test2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        }

        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string CategoryImg { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CategoryAdminID { get; set; }

        public virtual Admintb Admintb { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**This is my ViewModel which I am using to retrieve multiple models in a single View.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Test2.Models
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Admintb> AdminData { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Category> CategoryData { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Usertb> UserDt { get; set; }

        public Product Productmodel { get; set; }

        public Admintb Adminmodel { get; set; }

        public Usertb Usermodel { get; set; }

        public Category CategoryModel { get; set; }


        public Category Categryselection { get; set; }

    }


    public enum Category
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't really described a problem.  What have you tried and what isn't working?  You appear to be aware of the various components and data elements you require, so what happens when you put all that together in your code?

Comment: sounds like you need to fetch a list of categories and IDs from your database, convert that to a list of type SelectListItem, and add that list to your viewmodel (or to the viewbag, if you prefer), so that you can use that to populate the dropdownlist. It's a pretty common requirement, I'd be surprised if you can't find examples of it online already. Here's one super-simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50072463/5947043

Comment: ADyson how I will get these value from database ??..like he has giving hardcore text and value ... and i am working in multiple model in a single view so at the same time i have to post the data in product table in my database.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to write a code in your controller that get the category name and return the Id.

Something like this:

```
myProduct.category = categories.FirstOrDefault(c=> c.Name == categoryName).Id;
```

when your categoryName is the category what the user chosen.

It's realy simple.

good luck!

Comment: I think you've missed the point. And anyway, why would the the user choose a category _name_? Better to make the dropdown list have the IDs already there as the background value for each option. Then the ID is what gets submitted to the server. But you're thinking too far down the line, OP is struggling with how to populate the dropdownlist to begin with